Dispersion of a single tone signal on a microstrip transmission line
My question revolves around dispersive behavior on Microstrip lines.
I understand that on a microstrip high frequency signals will travel slower than lower frequencies. This is because the Eeff increases as frequencies increase.
My question is say you have a single tone frequency (ex: 1GHz pure sine wave). Since some of the energy travels in the air above the microstrip, and the rest in the dielectric, would the energy above the dielectric travel faster causing signal distortion as a function of microstrip length?
Sorry to ask this question here, I just cant find any info in this particular case much anywhere.

I think you are confused between 'single tone' and 'signal'.
A pure single tone, that started at t=-infinity and will last for ever has a single frequency, and so in a linear system, such as a microstrip, will only be changed in amplitude and phase/delay by passing through it, keeping the same shape.
A signal OTOH carries information, so must change with time, so must be composed of multiple frequencies. Even if you only switch a 1 GHz tone on and off, the discontinuity as you switch it will generate multiple other frequencies. The frequency dispersion of a microstrip will affect all of these differently, and so the nice clean edges of your signal will be altered and the signal distorted.

The system is linear: there is no waveform distortion of a pure tone, only change of amplitude and phase.

The energy travels only as a packet, and does so at one constant velocity. The dielectric around the strip (be it fully air, fully PCB substrate or a mixture) is the one thing that carries the energy.
(note that there could be multiple modes able to propagate in that waveguide, and I don't think different modes always have the same speed, but that won't be the case in a microstrip line at reasonable frequencies and dimensions)
The energy that travels at a different speed than that wave on the microstrip line is inherently an emission, i.e., radiating away from the line. In a microstrip line, you can't fully eliminate that, but you can limit the amount, as it disturbs other things.

Except for special (degenerate) cases (say two polarizations in a square waveguide) different modes don't propagate at the same velocity. That's a big part of the reason that we avoid operating a waveguide (or transmission line) multimode.
